# In GitHub, Is it possible to tell who has already accessed a given file or folder?

Tags: security, github

Is there a way to tell who has opened a given file or folder in github? Not just downloaded it or who 'can' access it but who 'has' accessed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A user page history does not currently exist in GitHub. The closest thing you'll get is looking at who has forked your repository.

A best practice for sensitive/proprietary info on GitHub is to only add collaborators/teams to your private repos that you are comfortable sharing information with.

Comment: In addition, if you've accidentally committed sensitive information to a public repository, you must assume it's completely public.  If that was a password, key, or token, revoke it and replace it.